# Firebase Android FCM INVALID_SENDER when trying to get token

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created a google-services.json file and added to my android project but when I tried to get a token I received this exception:

```
{
Java.IO.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: INVALID_SENDER ---> Java.Util.Concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: INVALID_SENDER ---> Java.IO.IOException: INVALID_SENDER
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at VTInRoomApp.Droid.XamarinForms.MainActivityXam.OnComplete (Android.Gms.Tasks.Task task) [0x00039] in T:\Work\VT\Dev\Mobile\Xamarin\VTInRoomApp\VTInRoomApp\VTInRoomApp.Android\XamarinForms\MainActivityXam.cs:157 
  --- End of managed Java.IO.IOException stack trace ---
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: INVALID_SENDER
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0:14)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$getToken$2$FirebaseMessaging(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0:1)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$$Lambda$3.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:2)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: INVALID_SENDER
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:5)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:8)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0:10)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: INVALID_SENDER
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.handleResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0:7)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.lambda$extractResponseWhenComplete$0$GmsRpc(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0:1)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc$$Lambda$1.then(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:3)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc$$Lambda$0.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:5)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:8)
    at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzz.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@17.0.0)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:5)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzp.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@17.0.0:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzr.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@17.0.0:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzf.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@17.0.0:14)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6157)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
}
```

Did I mess up when I created the google-servies.json or is it something in my code?

Thank you very much

Comment: Hi ,did you follow the official docs fully : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/firebase-cloud-messaging?

Comment: Yes I did. I got it work for one build. But every build after that I continued to receive the Invalid_Sender error.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this error caused by the json file. Check the information below to confirm.

1. Check that you have copied your file in correct project folder and have  set the Build Action to `GoogleServicesJson`.
2. Check the file is correct and matches with latest
   downloaded google-services.json file in FCM.
3. Check that is there any duplicate file of google-services.json present in your project.
4. Please note when `google-services.json` is added to the project (and the `GoogleServicesJson` build action is set), the build process extracts the `client ID` and `API` key and then adds these credentials to the merged/generated `AndroidManifest.xml` that resides at `obj/Debug/android/AndroidManifest.xml`. If you could confirm everything is  correect, delete the bin and obj to clean and rebuild and reopen the project may helpful.
5. If you still have this issue, create a new project to follow the steps in the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows

Answer (score -1):

> Try this

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
      if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());
        return;
      }

      // Get new FCM registration token
      String token = task.getResult();

      // Log and toast
      String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
      Log.d(TAG, msg);
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```